# Software Development Training/Projects

Tags: gratis, software-development, web-development, cross-platform, children

Not sure how to ask this. I have attempted to search for this but it's extremely difficult to find software and not just training seminars for it.

The basic functionality I would like would be a piece of software that has **varying levels of projects** from beginner to intermediate, preferably some **tutorials** and maybe even a built in **IDE**. The projects should be something **interesting** and fun to develop, the majority hopefully not taking too long to make.

As for languages supported, I would want **popular languages** not languages designed specifically to learn software development. The initial languages that comes to mind is **Java, C-based, Perl, Groovy/Grails, Ruby, Python etc**. If it's other languages than great, I am looking to improve my skill set.

Web-App would be an option but I think I would *prefer* something local. I would like something more than a simple list of different projects, something that will be more extensive and hopefully have a community behind it.

Not sure if this exists, if not I will just continue checking out code golf and playing with it.

I know this can be a vague question, please comment to help narrow things down and I will update regularly. I am not positive of all of the parameters that should be here.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cyber-dojo.com/ might be worth a look. 
It's a web-app intended for learning Test Driven Development in groups.

It allows you set up a session that multiple participants can join. They can then complete the selected challenge in the Language/test framework combination. After which each step in completing the challenge can be played back to facilitate learning from the process.

Comparing with your requirements it has a
 - Very good range of languages supported including all that you have listed.
 - Quite a long list of little projects/exercises to try. They quite interesting to solve, though are not graded by difficulty.
 - Provides built-in though somewhat primitive IDE functionality.

**Language/test frameworks supported:**

C#,
C++ GoogleTest,
C++ assert,
Clojure,
CoffeeScript,
Erlang,
Go,
Groovy JUnit,
Groovy Spock,
Haskell,
Java Approval,
Java Cucumber,
Java JUnit,
Java JUnit Mockito,
Javascript,
PHP,
Perl,
Python,
Ruby,
Ruby Approval,
Ruby Cucumber,
Ruby Rspec

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. As it is although it isn't a link only answer it could be improved quite a bit to be a high quality answer.